# Missing quote when sharing a link to Messenger

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, fbsdksharekit

I want to be able to send a link to Facebook Messenger along with a message. On their doc they say I need to assign a value to variable `quote`, but no success, the link is present but not the quote...

**Here is their doc:**

```
/**
  Some quote text of the link.

 If specified, the quote text will render with custom styling on top of the link.
 @return The quote text of a link
 */
@property (nonatomic, copy, nullable) NSString *quote;
```

I'm using their library: `pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '6.5.2'` on Swift so I import it in my bridging-header.

**Here is the chunk of code where im using it:**

```
   private func openFacebookMessenger(message: String, urlString: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        let shareLinkContent = ShareLinkContent()
        shareLinkContent.contentURL = url
        shareLinkContent.quote = message
        
        let dialog = MessageDialog()
        dialog.shareContent = shareLinkContent
        dialog.shouldFailOnDataError = true
        if dialog.canShow {
            dialog.show()
        }
    }
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that the quote is replaced by a meta data element from the page/url?

Comment: Did you try setting `title` or `description` instead of `quote`?

Comment: @OleksiiNezhyborets  yes :(

Comment: The latest version (9.0.0 as of today) doesn't allow setting `title` or `description`.

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook Document says that the Additional Features like **Hashtags** and **Quote Sharing** are supported when using **Share dialog**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios

*When you use the Facebook **share dialog**, you have additional options that aren't available when you share by using the API.*

I see you are using MessageDialog, so that could be the reason it is not working. Try using ShareDialog instead if you want to use quote.

Comment: But I want to share through Facebook messenger, not Facebook app... MessageDialog is meant to share with Facebook message.

Comment: Yes, I understand you want to share it via Facebook messenger, but Facebook seems to say that these additional features are available only in ShareDialog. To verify you can change to ShareDialog and check if the quote appears. If it does then you will have more clarity.  Then you can write a feedback to facebook to check if these feature can also be used with MessageDialog and if not you can ask for alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

My first guest is that the quote is shown when you have already share it, just bellow your answer not in the screen you have shown.

*You can allow people to highlight text to appear as a quote with a shared link. You can also predefine a quote, such as a single quote in an article, to appear with the shared link. In both cases, the quote appears in its own field, separate from the user's comments.*

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios